# Verificar se um e-mail foi digitado em campo de texto com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde!

Como faço para verificar se um e-mail foi digitado dentro de um campo de texto?

Preciso identificar quando o usuário clica fora do campo, se foi digitado um e-mail ou somente um nome, por exemplo.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui o cara colocou no submit do form, mas pode ser no onblur do campo.

Neste caso você usa Regex e o seletor do JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form1").submit(function(){
       var email = $("#email").val();
       if(email != "") {
           var filtro = /^([w-]+(?:.[w-]+)*)@((?:[w-]+.)*w[w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
           if(filtro.test(email)) {
               alert("Este endereço de email é válido!");
               return true;
           } else {
               alert("Este endereço de email não é válido!");
               return false;
           }
       } else {
           alert('Digite um email!'); return false;
       }
   });
```

});

Fonte: http://rogeralmeida.com.br/blog/2011/06/12/validacao-de-email-utilizando-expressoes-regulares-e-jquery/

Comment: Obrigado Shura 16!